# Parse.com - querying Installation table returns 0 even though there are two entries in the table

Tags: installation, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com backend and hybrid Android/iOS clients for my app. I have installed my client on two Android devices and enabled push notifications. I see two entries in 'Installation' table in Parse.com dashboard portal.

I want to query the installation table from my JS code, I issued a simple query to find out how many installations are there,

```
var Installation = Parse.Object.extend("Installation");
var query = new Parse.Query(Installation);
query.find({
        success: function(results) {
             console.log('Returned installation objects length: ' + results.length);
        },
        error: function() {
             console.error("Installation object lookup failed");
        }
});
```

I always see 0 results returned even though there are two entries in Installation table.

I tried above code both in client side with client id and JS key and through cloud code using master key but the result is always 0.

Is querying an Installation table allowed? If so is there a special way to query it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
var Installation = Parse.Object.extend("Installation");
var query = new Parse.Query(Installation);
```

If I change the above two lines to:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
```

Now I see results returned correctly to my query. I have only tested above code using CloudCode with masterkey and I have not checked from client using client (JS) key.